# Idiomatic move of last vector element to another variable in C++

Tags: c++, stl

I want to remove the last element from vector `v` and copy it to variable `q`. Is there a more concise way of doing it than this:

```
vector<int> v{3, 1, 4, 1};
int q = v.back();

v.pop_back();
```

Comment: `Why pop_back() doesn't return the value or reference to removed element?` Well, it obviously can't return a reference - what storage would it refer to, seeing as the element has been removed? As to why it doesn't return a value - it can't do that while providing strong exception safety guarantee; it can't keep the vector intact If `T`'s copy-constructor throws while attempting to return the value.

Comment: @Igor Thanks. Of course, returning a reference would not make sense. I removed that question, since it is a duplicate and stack overflow police already got on my case.